# Generate Admin URL from frontend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, url

I have to generate secure Admin URL in the frontend, for example in Magento 1.9 i can achieve it like this:

```
$adminUrl = Mage::getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array( 'order_id' => $order->getId()));
```

how can i achieve this in Magento 2.3 ?

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39737477/7562347

Comment: you can also vote up answer by click on up arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this code

```
private $HelperBackend;
private $urlBuilder;

public function __construct(
    ............................................
    \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $HelperBackend,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
    ............................................
  ) {
    ......................................
    $this->HelperBackend = $HelperBackend;
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    ......................................
}

public function getOrderUrlAdmin($order_id)
{
    $order_id = 12;
    $admin_name = $this->HelperBackend->getAreaFrontName();
    $link = $admin_name . "/" . "sales/order/view/order_id/";
    $order_link = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($link) . $order_id;
    return $order_link;
}
```